# How to remove objects on touch in android

Tags: object, imageview, hidden

I am new in android game development. Right now developing an Hidden Object game for android phones.
my question is how to remove an object on touch?
if player touch the object how can it will be removed. i tried on click listener with imageview. but not know what to do next..here is my code

setContentView(R.layout.level1);

```
    bowTie = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bowtie);

    bowTie.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ???? what goes here ??? 
            is it: finisht():
 or
  destroy();
     or
     bowTie.remove();

        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: this dont remove the object but maybe help you. `v.setVisibility(View.GONE);` This only hidden the view.

Comment: @stel ok. this line will be add within the listener.is it right? where i have writen question marks etc